# Goland run config console is wrapping lines before the end

Tags: goland

For some reason the Goland console has started adding a line wrap well before the end of the screen when I run a debug configuration:

[image]

This is not happening when run the same command in another terminal or IDE, and I can't find any docs on settings I might have tweaked to make this happen. How do I get it to stop wrapping the lines like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a known issue in GoLand. Feel free to follow [GO-12814](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-12814).

As a workaround, you can invoke *Help | Find Action | Registry*, find `go.run.processes.with.pty` and disable it.